# Cannot use 'KEYS' with redis-cluster

Tags: php, caching, redis, redis-cluster, predis

One of the applications that I am working on recently moved from `redis` to `redis cluster`. Now I have been using the `keys` command to get all the keys under a keyspace. But now it is saying `Cannot use 'KEYS' with redis-cluster`. The application written in Laravel and I am using `Predis` as the redis client.

I am storing a tree response in the redis and it is under a namespace of `parent:child:ItemID` format. So I have entries like

```
 parent:child:1
 parent:child:2
 parent:child:3
```

and each of these keys has JSON associated with it. I am fetching each of the JSON entries looping through the keys. The code is as follows:

```
$keys = $this->redis->keys('parent:child:*');

if (!empty($keys)) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $cacheData[] = json_decode($this->redis->get($key));
    }
}
```

Now this is returning the above mentioned error. Is there any alternative ways to get all the data under this specified namespace ?

Comment: As @diogo-sgrillo marked you should avoid using keys() and prefer using scan() instead. And if you're using JSON mostly you might want to consider using RedisJSON.io

Answer (score -3):

From the official [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys)

> **Warning**: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

If you are using `predis` you can do like in this [example](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.1.1/examples/redis_collections_iterators.php#L43-L47):

```
foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($this->redis, 'parent:child:*') as $key) {
    $cacheData[] = json_decode($this->redis->get($key));
}
```

Comment: This is also not working in the case of cluster as predis is throwing error that says `Cannot Use SCAN with redis-cluster`

Comment: Can't downgrade this answer.
Same as @HappyCoder - ```Cannot Use SCAN with redis-cluster```

Comment: make sure you're connecting as a cluster (using arrays): f.e: `$client = new Predis\Client(['tcp://10.0.0.1?alias=first-node', ['host' => '10.0.0.2', 'alias' => 'second-node']]);`